# How to filter out each polygon from its list of neighbors with sf::st_intersects

Tags: r, polygon, r-sf

I need to extract the neighboring polygons for each polygon in an `sf` dataset.

Here's a quick example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

demo(nc, ask = FALSE, verbose = FALSE)
nc <- nc %>% 
  mutate(polygon_id = row_number())
```

I have managed to extract the neighbors with `sf::st_intersects`

```
neighbors <- st_intersects(nc, nc)
neighbors[[5]]
[1]  5  6  9 16 28
```

The issue is that each polygon (here, 5) is being included in the list of neighbors. Using only one `nc` dataset gives me the same result

```
neighbors <- st_intersects(nc)
neighbors[[5]]
[1]  5  6  9 16 28
```

Any tips on how to filter out the actual polygon from the list of adjacent/neighboring polygons?

Comment: I managed to solve it using ```st_touches``` instead of ```st_intersects```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. This question could have many solutions.  But the simple answer for this question: `"Any tips on how to filter out the actual polygon from the list of adjacent/neighboring polygons?"`,  was accomplished using the Jupyter Lab IDE with the R kernel. The following code provides one way to answer the question.

There are 100 counties in the nc dataset. This code displays the selected county in color and shows all the neighboring counties. This code works for any of the 100 counties in nc. The county 100 was selected here.

Code:

```
nc1 <- nc %>% mutate(c_id = 1:nrow(nc))        
n = 100                  
grp <- st_intersects(nc1, nc1[n,1]   , sparse = F ) 

neighborhood <- nc1[grp,]
neighborhood 

plot(neighborhood$geom)
plot(nc1[n,1], col = 'blue', add = TRUE)   #
```

This code is easily extended. I wrote a quick little function that displays the names of the neighboring countries (not shown here), but this question seems to be most likely a plotting related question.

The plot is shown at  [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in2E3.png)